# Creating a parameter script with PowerShell to be called by another script

Tags: powershell

I have a PowerShell script that works. For maintenance reasons I want to create another script where I'll put all the parameters that I'll call from my first script.

How can I create and call the parameter file?

**Here is my script:**

```
param([string] $dataSource = "server")

$Stamp = (Get-Date).toString("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss")
$Stamp1 = (Get-Date).toString("yyyy-MM-dd")
$Logfile = "E:\PowerShell\Log\file$stamp1.log"

$file = "file$stamp1.csv"
$extractFile = @"
E:\PowerShell\Output\$file 
"@

[string]$sqlCommand1 =get-content -path E:\PowerShell\SQL\sql.sql
[string]$sqlCommand =$sqlCommand1

$authentication =  ("User Id= user ;Password=pswd;" -f $plainCred.Username, $plainCred.Password)

Add-Type -assemblyname system.data

$factory = [System.Data.Common.DbProviderFactories]::GetFactory  ("Teradata.Client.Provider")

$connection = $factory.CreateConnection() 

$connection.ConnectionString = "Data Source = $dataSource;Connection Pooling Timeout=300;$authentication"  

$connection.Open()

if ($connection.State -eq 'Open') {$logstring ="Connexion réussite"} else { $logstring ="echec Connexion" }

$command = $connection.CreateCommand()
$command.CommandText = $sqlCommand

$adapter = $factory.CreateDataAdapter()
$adapter.SelectCommand = $command

$dataset = new-object System.Data.DataSet


try
{
[void] $adapter.Fill($dataset)

$dataset.Tables | Select-Object -Expand Rows

}
finally
{
$connection.Close()
}

if (!$dataset) {$logstring1 ="extraction vide"} else {$logstring1     ="extraction réussite"}

($DataSet.Tables[0] | ConvertTo-Csv  -delimiter ";" -NoTypeInformation )   -replace '"', "" | Out-File $extractFile -Force 

$datafileExists = Test-Path $extractFile

if ($datafileExists)
    {
        $logstring2 ="Fichier data créé"
    } 
else 
    {
       $logstring2 ="Fichier data non créé"
    }

Add-content $Logfile -value ($Stamp+':'+$logstring) 
Add-content $Logfile -value ($Stamp+':'+$logstring1) 
Add-content $Logfile -value ($Stamp+':'+$logstring2)
```

I created a file of parameters

```
$Stamp1 = (Get-Date).toString("yyyy-MM-dd")
$Logfile = "E:\PowerShell\Log\file$stamp1.log"
$file = "file$stamp1.csv"
$extractFile = @"
E:\PowerShell\Output\$file 
"@
$authentication =  ("User Id= user ;Password=paswd;" -f      $plainCred.Username, $plainCred.Password)
$Stamp = (Get-Date).toString("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss")
```

and I call it from my first script like that :

```
$ScriptPath = Split-Path $MyInvocation.InvocationName
& "$ScriptPath\param.ps1"
```

but my variables are not recognised, I have these errors:

```
Out-File : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'FilePath' because it is null.
At E:\PowerShell\script\Soft.ps1:59 char:104
+ ...  "" | Out-File $extractFile -Force
+                    ~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Out-File], ParameterBindingValidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationErrorNullNotAllowed,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.OutFileCommand

Test-Path : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Path' because it is null.
At E:\PowerShell\script\Soft.ps1:61 char:29
+ $datafileExists = Test-Path $extractFile
+                             ~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Test-Path], ParameterBindingValidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationErrorNullNotAllowed,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.TestPathCommand

Add-Content : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Path' because it is null.
At E:\PowerShell\script\Soft.ps1:78 char:14
+  Add-content $Logfile -value ($Stamp+':'+$logstring)
+              ~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Add-Content], ParameterBindingValidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationErrorNullNotAllowed,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.AddContentCommand

Add-Content : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Path' because it is null.
At E:\PowerShell\script\Soft.ps1:79 char:13
+ Add-content $Logfile -value ($Stamp+':'+$logstring1)
+             ~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Add-Content], ParameterBindingValidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationErrorNullNotAllowed,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.AddContentCommand

Add-Content : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Path' because it is null.
At E:\PowerShell\script\Soft.ps1:80 char:13
+ Add-content $Logfile -value ($Stamp+':'+$logstring2)
+             ~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Add-Content], ParameterBindingValidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationErrorNullNotAllowed,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.AddContentCommand
```

Comment: Ehhh... create another `.ps1` file, define your parameter arguments and call the script? It's unclear what the issue is here

Comment: well i created the second file and called it in the first but my parameters are note recognised

Comment: Show us both scripts + any errors you receive

Comment: I edited my post with those informations

Comment: Replace `&` with `.`

Comment: Tanks a lot !! it worked as it had to

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IF you use '&' you execute the ps1 and the variables created are available within that scope. you can change the scope like this:

```
$test # default scope
$global:test # global scope
$script:test # script scope
```

The better solution is to use '.' in stead of '&' so you 're code from the ps1 is included in the other ps1.

so the scope is in the same because it is in the same script.

Comment: Tanks a lot for the explanation. it helped a lot !!